# Load Specific XML Node Values C#

Tags: c#, xml

I am trying to get the attribute values of all nodes with the tag name "Event" into a comboBox on a WindowsForm.  I have tried this code below, however, nothing populates in the comboBox.

```
 if (selectEventComboBox.SelectedIndex != -1)
    {
        string filePath = 
              Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments) 
              + "\\" + selectFileComboBox.SelectedItem.ToString() 
              + "dogs.xml";
        XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
        doc.Load(filePath);

        XmlNodeList eventList = doc.GetElementsByTagName("Event");
        for (int count = 0; count < eventList.Count; count++)
        {
            selectEventComboBox.Items.Add(eventList[count].Attributes.ToString());
        }
    }
```

Comment: difficult to comment without seeing (some of) the xml document

Comment: Have you tried stepping through the code with debugger?  If yes, then does the debugger show that the document has loaded properly?

Comment: I'm trying to add the xml but it looks horrible when you add it to the question event using the 'enter code' tag

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This works fine

```
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.Load("myxml.xml");
XmlNode root = doc.DocumentElement;
XmlNodeList nodeList = root.SelectNodes("//Event");

for (int i = 0; i < nodeList.Count; i++)
{
    Console.WriteLine("row: {0}, InnerText: {1}, ID: {2}",i, nodeList[i].InnerText, nodeList[i].Attributes["id"].Value);
}
```

Contents of myxml.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<root>
    <Event id="1">Event one</Event>
    <Event id="2">Event two</Event>
    <Event id="3">Event three</Event>
    <Event id="4">Event four</Event>
</root>
```

[image]

Comment: I think the problem is that I am trying to get the attribute not the inner text for the node.  So I have an example where it is <Event id="123456">.  I want to display the 123456